# Does there exist a sequence with these properties?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a sequence $a_n\in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ such that $$\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty}~~~ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n >0$$

and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n\cdot n^2} = \infty~~?$$

P.S. I posted the logical next question here [Does there exist a non-increasing sequence with these properties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624574/does-there-exist-a-non-increasing-sequence-with-these-properties)

Comment: The second condition is impossible for $a_n\in \Bbb N$ because  then  $0<1/(a_nn^2)\leq 1/n^2 $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^2)<\infty.$

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac{\ln n}{n}$

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan, Then $\sum 1/(n^2a_n)$  converges.

Comment: Sorry edited just now

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n= 1/n^2$ when $n$ is even, and $1$ when $n$ is odd.  Then the average converges to $1/2$ and the sum is $\infty$.

Comment: The OP asks for a sequence of natural numbers, though.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs  Oops.  Gotta read all the words.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs sorry. my mistake. the second condition doesn't make sense for natural numbers.

Comment: What I see in the Q is $\sum (a_n n^2)^{-1}.$  For $a_n\in \Bbb N$ we have  $0<(a_nn^2)^{-1}\leq n^{-2}$ so the sum must be finite because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}=\pi^2 /6$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet When $n$ is even, $a_nn^2 = 1,$ so the summand is $1$ infintely often.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for your answer. I realized that I mean to ask about non-increasing sequences, but this is illuminating nonetheless (i've now asked a seperate question in a new post).

Comment: The Q has been re-defined by an edit. My prior comments were toward the first version, which said $a_n\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ah, now your comments make sense to me.  I was rather perplexed.